# CKAN Datastore Create API : Resource name enters as "Unnamed resource"

Tags: ckan

I have created a datastore using CKAN datastore create API

Code follows:

```
   { "resource": {
            "package_id": "{{package_ID}}"
        }, 
      "fields": [   {"id": "name"}, 
                    {"id": "age"} 
                ], 
       "records": [ { "name": "Alex", "age": "30"}, {"name": "Britto", "age": "28"} ]

    }
```

It creates a new resource under my specified package. The records enters correctly and i can view the records in the CKAN . But the resource file shows as "Unnamed resource". How can i set the name of the resource in the API input. Is it possible with datastore API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the [`datastore_create`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/datastore.html#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_create) function. In that case, you can use the `resource` key to pass any argument that you would normally pass to [`resource_create`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create). In particular, you can set the resource's title via the `name` key:

```
{
    "resource": {
        "package_id": "{{package_ID}}",
        "name": "human-readable name of your resource"
    }, 
    ...
}
```